# MySQL replication: how to safely propagate ignored table structure changes from master to slave?

Tags: mysql, replication, alter-table

We have a MySQL database with a replication set up (master to single slave).
Some tables are skipped from replication (they are listed in `Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table` when calling `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`). In the slave database the ignored table is present with no data.

The problem is the structure of one of the ignored tables was ALTER'ed on master and this change needs to be propagated to slave.

What is simplest non-breaking way of achieving that?
Can I just run `ALTER TABLE` on slave, adding the necessary columns?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Tried it and it worked without breaking anything.